# got an length eroor when using read_parquet function

Tags: pandas, pyarrow, fastparquet

When i use read_parquet method to read parquet file, it occurs `Column 8 named hostIp expected length 548 but got length 549` error, hostIP is one column in REQUIRED_COLUMNS.

```py
import pandas as pd

REQUIRED_COLUMNS = [...]
path = ...
data = pd.read_parquet(path, columns=REQUIRED_COLUMNS)
```

When i iterate each column in REQUIRED_COLUMNS to call read_parquet, it successed.

```py
for col in REQUIRED_COLUMNS:
    columns = [col]
    data = pd.read_parquet(path, columns=columns)
```

And i check that the number of raws is 548 for each column in the above process.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting is because the `hostIp` column in your Parquet file has 549 rows, but the `read_parquet()` method is expecting it to have 548 rows.

The code you have provided shows that you are iterating over the `REQUIRED_COLUMNS` list and calling `read_parquet()` for each column individually. This works because each column has 548 rows. However, when you call `read_parquet()` with the `REQUIRED_COLUMNS` list as the `columns` argument, it will try to read all of the columns in the list, including the `hostIp` column, which has 549 rows. This is why you are getting the error.

To solve this problem, you can either:

- Change the `read_parquet()` method to only read the first 548 rows of the `hostIp` column.
- Remove the `hostIp` column from the `REQUIRED_COLUMNS` list.

Here is an example of how to change the `read_parquet()` method to only read the first 548 rows of the `hostIp` column:

```py
def read_parquet_with_limited_hostIp(path, columns):
    data = pd.read_parquet(path, columns=columns)
    hostIp_data = data["hostIp"][:548]
    return hostIp_data

hostIp_data = read_parquet_with_limited_hostIp(path, REQUIRED_COLUMNS)
```

Here is an example of how to remove the `hostIp` column from the `REQUIRED_COLUMNS` list:

```py
REQUIRED_COLUMNS = REQUIRED_COLUMNS[:7]
data = pd.read_parquet(path, columns=REQUIRED_COLUMNS)
```

Comment: I check that length of column `hostIp` is 548, and i use columns `['uuId', 'hostIp']` to read for test, it can read successful.